# Can I get the Amazon SWF usage limits for my account from the API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

According to [Amazon Simple Workflow Service Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html):

> **Limits on Workflow Executions**
>
> - Maximum open workflow executions: **100,000** per domain

However, the [Amazon SWF Limit Increase Form](https://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonSWF_Limit_Increase_Form) states:

> Amazon SWF users can create a maximum of 100 domains per account. [...] Upto **10,000** workflow executions can be open at a time in each domain, which means that upto a million executions can be open simultaneously in each user account.

Either way, Amazon can change the limit for customers who've requested it.

Is there a way of getting these figures from the API *for my account*, for a definitive answer?
Can I see them somewhere in the interface?

Comment: Related - [Amazon Simple Workflow Service Limits - Throttling limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html#swf-throttling-limits) - This list wasn't public, it is certainly better to know these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate limit information was recently added to CloudWatch:

- Rate limits relating to API usage such as `StartWorkflowExecution` can be seen in *All > SWF > API Usage Metrics*.
- Rate limits relating to decisions such as `ScheduleActivityTask` or `StartChildWorkflowExecution` are at *All >
  SWF > Decision Usage Metrics*.

Each API or Decision type has metrics for its *ProvisionedBucketSize* and *ProvisionedRefillRate*.

For example, [here is the rate limit for `StartChildWorkflowExecution`](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#metricsV2:graph=~(view~'singleValue~stacked~true~region~'us-east-1~yAxis~(left~(min~0)~right~(min~0))~metrics~(~(~'AWS*2fSWF~'ProvisionedBucketSize~'DecisionName~'StartChildWorkflowExecution)~(~'.~'ProvisionedRefillRate~'.~'.))~title~'StartChildWorkflowExecution);namespace=AWS/SWF;dimensions=DecisionName) (the link is for us-east-1):

[image]

There are also metrics for *ThrottledEvents* and *ConsumedCapacity*, so you can keep track of how much you use the API, and how often it fails.

A new CloudWatch dashboard shows all of the limits in one place: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#cw:dashboard=SWF

Answer (score 1):

There is currently nowhere you can see this on the SWF console or to get them by using the API. The only way I am aware of to either [raise](http://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonSWF_Limit_Increase_Form) or see your current limits, is to contact the AWS SWF team. The only URL I could find that sends a message to the team was the [one I linked above](http://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonSWF_Limit_Increase_Form).